# Issues adding SignalR.Client Nuget Package to a Monogame Android Project

Tags: android, xamarin, signalr, xamarin.android, monogame

Hello Stack Overflow Community

My problem is simply what you see in the title I cant get the signal R client pack into my Project In Visual Studio. Attempting to do so results in this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.          0

I need the package and have been trying various workarounds but have not yet came out successful. Any tips or info would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a common PCL in your project? In that case you should install SignalR in there

Comment: Will a PCL allow me to declare an instance of IHubProxy or HubConnection in the android project. I believe I may have done the equivalent by referencing a pc version of the same project but I have to manage signalR within the pc project @xleon 16.

Comment: Sorry it may be worth mentioning also the fact both projects are across different solutions. I am relativily new to using multiple projects/solutions. @xleon 16

Comment: I tried to add SignalR to an Android project and I got the very same error. I think this could do the trick, try installing this component ( https://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr ) in your android project (you will need to remove newtonsoft json if it´s already installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to add SignalR to an Android project and I got the very same error. I >think this could do the trick, try installing this component ( >components.xamarin.com/view/signalr ) in your android project (you will need to >remove newtonsoft json if it´s already installed) – xleon

This is just a Repost of xleons answer so I can mark the question as answered I am new to stack overflow so I hope this is appropriate.

Thanks for the Help @xleon This was exactly the solution I was looking for

Comment: Now you can mark your own answer as correct I think. Normally you wait for and answer (not a comment) to be in place so you can mark it as correct

Comment: Okay will do (have to wait 24 hours)but at least there is a working solution for those who may need it in the future